# Injecting entity data automatically when rendering

Tags: redux, normalizr

Is there a way to automatically inject deeply nested entity data when rendering?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let boardId = ownProps.params.id

  return {
    id: boardId,
    // is there an easier method to do this?
    comments: state.entities.boards[boardId].comments.map(id => {
      return Object.assign({}, state.entities.comments[id], {
        user: state.entities.users[state.entities.comments[id].user]
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing "automatic", but three approaches that can abstract that sort of thing:

1) Use "selector" functions to encapsulate state shape, and apply memoization.  See [Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) and [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)

2) Use one of the many [immutable data utility libraries](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md) out there to do some nested getting/setting

3) Use [Redux-ORM](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) to abstract working with that relational data in your Redux store.